# "Relief" function from the Raster Terrain Analysis plugin in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, terrain

I am using QGIS 3.0, where I can't find the [Raster Terrain Analysis plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_raster_terrain.html).

I am under the impression that the plugin was embedded into the QGIS 3.0 version, as under `"Raster --> Analysis"` there are options for `"Hillshade"`, `"Slope"` and `"TRI"` for no relief.

If this is the case, does anyone know how to obtain `"Relief"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also an alternative option from the GRASS GIS library.

The module called [`r.relief`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.relief.html) that does the same job as [`"Relief"`](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_raster_terrain.html#raster-terrain-analysis-plugin) in Raster Terrain Analysis Plugin.

> Creates a shaded relief map from an elevation map (DEM).

[image: Relief_GRASS_GIS]

QGIS 3.0.3-Girona

Comment: Thankyou @Taras, this too has been very useful.

Comment: @Bodhi, you are always welcome

Answer (score 6):

If you search for Terrain analysis in the Processing toolbox you will find what you  want. The tool moved from `Raster -> Terrain analysis` to `Processing Toolbox -> Raster Terrain analysis`:

[image]

I am using QGIS 3.4